# How can I use decltype to get the type of a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, c++builder-2010

I'm working on some code using decltype in CodeGear RAD Studio. I've tried the naive solution, which looks not unlike this:

```
int main(int, char**) {
    int i;
    int &ir = i;
    decltype((ir)) ir_clone = ir;
}
```

Of course, this fails to compile: Internal Compiler Error. I rather suspect that there is nothing particularly wrong with that code and there is a compiler bug regarding reference expressions. (Incidentally, g++ has no problem with the code and compiles it fine.) That doesn't help solve the problem, however, as the platform is non-negotiable.

If, above, I had written

```
    decltype(ir) ir_clone = ir; /* No extra parens */
```

it compiles and works as expected. However, the problem doesn't end there, since that doesn't correctly compute constness from the environment. In particular:

```
struct S { int i; } s;
const S* p = &s;
decltype(p->i)   i0 = s.i; /* i0 is an int */
decltype((p->i)) i1 = s.i; /* i1 is a const int& */
```

If I don't use the parens to make the argument an expression, I lose the constness of the argument, which I need.

Another tool I can use is simple templates, like so:

```
template<class T> struct unref     { typedef T type; }
template<class T> struct unref<T&> { typedef T type; }
```

That lets me strip away the reference portion of a type, by using `unref<int&>::type`.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to put all these tools together to get a successful expression for the type I need. For one of things I need, I'm working on a generalized macro that does 'foreach'. (Yes, I know Boost does it better.) It needs to handle the following scenarios:

```
(vector<int>) vi          => vector<int>
(vector<int>&)vir         => vector<int>
(const vector<int>) cvi   => const vector<int>
(const vector<int>&)cvir  => const vector<int>
(const P*) cp->vi         => const vector<int>
(P*) p->vi                => vector<int>
```

So far, my simple attempts fail:

```
unref<decltype(cp->vi)>   /* is vector<int>, not what I need. */
unref<decltype((cp->vi))> /* is const vector<int>, which is right. */

unref<decltype(vir)>      /* is vector<int>, which is right. */
unref<decltype((vir))>    /* Internal Compiler Error, which is a headache. */
```

Any ideas to get me on the right track? Hopefully there's just something simple I'm missing. Maybe I'm attacking the problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: frankly, the description is too long, and i guess with typos (declspec), and not clear why decltype is needed at all if there are only simple known types used. i understand that it's a contrived example, but it doesn't help to understand the problem.

Comment: Typos corrected. declspec was wrong.

As for the length of the question, I was trying to 'show my work', so as to get more precise answers.

If it helps, consider that a macro that uses this might look like `foreach(item, container)`. (Yes, I know Boost does it better.) I need to be able to intuit things about the type of the container in order to determine what kind of iterator object to use.

Comment: Awesome idea. Alas, `auto` is not yet supported by the compiler. But yes, that would solve almost all of the problems neatly. Even better (for this particular example) would be the C++0x `for` range statement. But alas, that, too, is not-yet-implemented.

Comment: Try a few silly `decltype` variations just to see if the compiler doesn't go stupid: `decltype((void(), ir))` for example.

Comment: even better, instead of writing macro (yikes), use `std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), [](value_type v) { /* whatever */});`

Comment: @GMan : Apparently, my compiler has gone stupid. I'd tried a few variations, but I hadn't tried the comma operator. decltype((0, ir)) works. If you'll reply as an answer, I'll accept it, since it does solve my problem.

Comment: And yeah, if I had lambda expressions available, this would likewise be moot (for foreach).

Comment: Aside: `unref` already exists as `std::remove_reference` in C++0x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making a different, more complex expression that results in the same type that you want, such as:

```
decltype((void(), ir))
```

I couldn't tell you why it fixes it, but sometimes a different expression will do the trick.

Comment: @alf: Did `void()` not work? I used it because if the type of `ir` overloads `operator,(int, ...)`, you're solution might break. (Unlikely, yes, but for the sake of generality.)

Comment: Aye, void() doesn't navigate around whatever the compiler bug is. And you're right on the overloaded comma operator. After a little more playing, I find that `decltype(((void)0, ir))` works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::remove_reference (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).