# Using std extent with a template array

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The following is my source code that I have written to test the usage of std::extent to check the sizes of template array instantiations as compile time constants:

```
//classA.h

#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using std::is_same;
using std::extent;
using std::remove_reference;
using std::size_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T> class A;
template<typename T>
using array2As = A<T>[2];

template<typename T> 
void doSomething (const array2As<T>&);

template<typename T>
class A{
  public:
  A(T);
  private:
  friend void doSomething<>(const array2As<T>&);
  A()=delete;
  A(const A&)=delete; 
  A& operator=(const A&)=delete;
  T elem;
};

template<typename T>
A<T>::A(T elem){
  static_assert(is_same<T,int>::value || is_same<T,double>::value, "Compilation error: type must be int or double");
  this->elem = elem;
}

template<typename T> void doSomething (const array2As<T>& a){

   static_assert(2 == extent<remove_reference<decltype(a)>>, "Compilation error: array must have exactly 2 elements");

//static_assert(2 == extent<a>, "Compilation error: array must have exactly 2 elements");
  
  const auto& obj1 = a[0];
  cout << obj1.elem << endl;
  const auto& obj2 = a[1];
  cout << obj2.elem << endl;
 return;
}

#include "classA.h"

int main (){
 
 array2As<int> a = {A(5),A(7)};
 doSomething<int>(a);
 array2As<double> b = {A(1.2),A(6.3)};
 doSomething<double>(b);

 return 0;
}
```

The above code fails to compile with the following error:

```
    In file included from main.cpp:1:
classA.h: In function ‘void doSomething(const A<T> (&)[2])’:
classA.h:42:60: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
   42 |    static_assert(2 == extent<remove_reference<decltype(a)>>, "Compilation error: array must have exactly 2 elements");
      |                                                            ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Now if I were to comment out the line in the code emitting this error, and instead uncomment the line below it commented out at present, that doesn't help either, as it results in a different error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
classA.h: In function ‘void doSomething(const A<T> (&)[2])’:
classA.h:43:31: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class, unsigned int <anonymous> > struct std::extent’
   43 |    static_assert(2 == extent<a>, "Compilation error: array must have exactly 2 elements");
      |                               ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

I am not sure whether decltype can be fed a reference parameter?

[How can I use decltype to get the type of a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970959/how-can-i-use-decltype-to-get-the-type-of-a-reference)

Presume I am doing everything right in terms of my usage of std::extent? What is causing this error? How can this error be resolved?

TIA

Comment: `decltype` uses parenthesis, not angle brackets. This is because it is an operator, not a template. Replace `decltype<a>` with `decltype(a)`. It is even right there in the link you posted.

Comment: @Mestkon thanks for pointing that out...I have rectified that in the edited post...but I think the compiler doesn't like the fact that I am passing a reference to decltype() as can be deduced from the new compilation error?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the reference to `decltype`, which handles references just fine. `std::remove_reference` is a class type which always has an extent of `0`. To get the type you passed into it with references stripped you have to get the `type` member of the `std::remove_reference` type by `typename std::remove_reference<...>::type` or `std::remove_reference_t<...>`. This is the same with `std::extent`. You are comparing `2` with a class name, which gives you the primary expression error. Here you have to get the extent value by `std::extent<...>::value` or `std::extent_v<...>`.

Comment: @Mestkon Thanks your suggestions resolved the issue....if you could post them as an answer I could accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `decltype` is not a template, it is an `operator`. Therefore you have to use parenthesis `()` not angle brackets `<>` with it. So replace `decltype<a>` with `decltype(a)`.

Secondly, the classes defined in `<type_traits>` are not to be used as the trait types or trait values themselves, but the trait classes contain a member typedef or a member value to inspect for the trait result.

When you compare `2` with `std::extent<U>`, then you are comparing `2` with a class name, which gives you the `expected primary-expression` error you are observing. What you really want to do is to compare `2` with the `value` member of the `std::extent` type trait which can be accessed as `std::extent<U>::value` (or `std::extent_v<U>` for `c++17`).

The same holds for `std::remove_reference<U>`. The extent of `std::remove_reference<U>` is always `0` because `std::remove_reference<U>` is itself always a class type unrelated to `U`. What you want in this case is to access the `type` member typedef of the `std::remove_reference` type trait which can be accessed as `typename std::remove_reference<U>::type` (or `std::remove_reference_t<U>` in `c++17`).

So the full expression you want to compare with looks like

```
// pre c++17
std::extent<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(a)>::type>::value
// c++17 and onwards
std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(a)>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::remove_reference` is a struct template, you must specify a type for the template parameter, but you pass a variable name. You might want

```
remove_reference<decltype(a)>::type
```

BTW discarding a reference for `std::extent` is unnecessary.

Comment: I am afraid both your suggestions turned out to be incorrect...or perhaps I didn't get the implication right? Anyways I have edited the question to show the compiler output.