# Using constexpr in a class template context

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constexpr

In my short test program, I am trying to emulate the approach outlined in the following post:

[How can I use decltype to get the type of a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970959/how-can-i-use-decltype-to-get-the-type-of-a-reference)

```
template<class T> struct unref     { typedef T type; }
template<class T> struct unref<T&> { typedef T type; }
```

The following is the source code:

```
//test.h

#include<cstddef>

using std::size_t;

template<class T>
  struct unref {typedef T type;};
template<class T> 
  struct unref<T&>{typedef T type;};

template<typename T>
class A{
   public:
   constexpr A(T);
   constexpr ~A();
   private:
   A()=delete; 
   A(const A&)=delete;
   A& operator=(const A&)=delete;
   private:
   T elem;
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
using arrayofAs = constexpr A<T>[N];
template<typename T> constexpr A<T>::A(T elem):elem(elem){}
template<typename T> constexpr A<T>::~A(){}

//main.cpp
#include "test.h"
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using std::is_same;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (){
arrayofAs<int,5> aofAints = {1,2,3,4,5};
arrayofAs<float,5> aofAfloats = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};

constexpr auto& refaofAints = aofAints;
constexpr auto& refaofAfloats = aofAfloats;

cout << is_same<unref<refaofAints>, aofAints>::value << endl;
cout << is_same<unref<refaofAfloats>, aofAfloats>::value << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
test.h:27:19: error: expected type-specifier before ‘constexpr’
   27 | using arrayofAs = constexpr A<T>[N];
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Any thoughts on why I am getting this error and what I need to change in order to resolve this error?

P:S: Without the `constexpr` declarations in the code, I was getting the compiler error that `refaofAints` was not a `constexpr` for the following usage:

```
cout << is_same<unref<refaofAints>, aofAints>::value << endl;
```

So I introduced the `constexpr` declarations with the intention of resolving this error.

TIA

Comment: `constexpr` is not part of a type. It is a non-type specifier in a declaration.

Comment: @user17732522 agree, and I presume my usage of constexpr in the source code is in keeping with that principle? If not, do you mind editing my code and pointing out where the usage is not in accordance with this principle?

Comment: `using arrayofAs = [...]` expects `[...]` to be a type. `constexpr` isn't part of the type. So it can't appear there. It belongs only on the declaration of a variable or function, e.g. on the declaration of `aofAints`, if you want to use `aofAints` in a compile-time context.

Comment: It will still fail however because `unref<refaofAints>` makes no sense. You declared `unref` to take a type as template argument, but `refaofAints` is a variable. All in all I don't understand what you are trying to do. I expect that you are on the wrong path to solve your actual overall problem based on your questions so far, although I don't know what that is.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for that. I see what you mean. I will change my code based on your inputs and test with the changes